# Organizing Files In Directories with Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

So I am wondering if there is any way to organize a directory on a mac with the terminal. I am a beginner with using the terminal and just seeing if this is possible.

I have a script that will scrape various pages and save certain data to a file (data irrelevant), such as this picture.
[directory that needs organizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvT0D.png)

I would like to know if I can write something that will read the file names and create directories that correspond. For example, it runs a loop that will read all files with "Year2014", create a folder named "Year2014", then place the files inside.

If you have any other questions, let me know!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a site for programmers to ask questions. You are expected to show your research and what you've tried so far to accomplish your goal. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @CullenStone : I don't see how this problem is related to your **terminal** program. You just want to write a program which shuffles files around. Whether you run the program from the terminal or in any other way is not relevant.

Comment: @CullenStone : Also, if you want to discuss a programming problem, we need to see the program you have written to solve this problem. I don't think you are searching for a simple bash-command which magically is doing what you want to achieve, do you?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "Yes", and the longer answer is there are many ways to do it. Since you are using bash (or any POSIX shell), you have *parameter expansion with substring removal* available to help you trim text from the end of each filename to isolate the `"YearXXXX"` part of the filename that you can then use to (1) create the directory, and (2) move the file into the newly created directory.

**Presuming Filenames Formatted `WeekXXYearXXXX.txt`**

Take for example a simple `for` loop where the loop variable `f` will contain each filename in turn. You can isolate the `"WeekXX"` part of the name by using a parameter expansion that trims from the right of the string trough `'Y'` leaving whatever `"WeekXX"` is. (save the result in a temporary variable) You can then use that temp variable to remove the `"WeekXX"` text from the original filename leaving `"YearXXXX.txt"`. You then simply remove `".txt"` from the first to arrive at the directory name to put the file in.

Scriptwise it would look like:

```
for f in *.txt; do              ## loop over .txt files using variable $f
    tmp="${f%%Y*}"              ## remove though 'Y' from right
    dname="${f#$tmp}"           ## remove contents of tmp from left
    dname="${dname%.txt}"       ## remove .txt
    mkdir -p "$dname"           ## create dname (no error if exists)
    mv "$f" "$dname"            ## move $f to $dname
done
```

Where the temporary variable used is `tmp` and the final directory name is stored in the variable `dname`.

(**note:** you may want to use `mv -i` if you want `mv` to prompt before overwriting if the filename already exists in the target directory)

You can refer to `man bash` under the **Parameter Expansion** heading to read the specifics of each expansion which (among many more) are described as:

```
${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```

Note this set of parameter expansions is POSIX so it will work with any POSIX shell, while most of the remaining expansions are bashisms (bash-only)

Let me know if you have further questions.